# Loading new URL without page refresh and updating page contents with the content of the updated URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an online store project which displays product on the `products.php` page using a `$_GET` ID parameter to filter with categories, and on clicking the name (link) of each product, I created a function which changes the contents of the current page (`products.php`) with the contents of `product_details.php` and updates the url to the `product_details.php`.

However, there is a little drawback with this function. If I click through "go back" button, it actually goes back to the previous page
(`product.php`) but the contents of `product_details.php` remains.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".view", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#loader').css("display","inline-block");

    setTimeout(function() {  
        $("#products").load(url + " #details", function() {
            history.pushState('obj', 'Product_Details', url);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

My "go back" button

```
<a href="Javascript:history.go(-1);"><button class="col-12 btn btn-secondary shadow text-white"><i class="ti-arrow-left"></i> Go back</button></a>
```

Please is there a better way around this ?

Comment: Just so the loading animation can go on.. to let users know their request is going on

Comment: It shows just less than a second.. besides the set timeout works well..

Comment: Help with the above question would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you want onpopstate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate